# Carry Last Observation Forward by ID in R

Tags: r, zoo, na

I have daily observations with lots of missing values and am trying to propagate the first non-missing value through a vector for each individual.

In the searching that I have done so far, I discovered the `na.locf` function in the `zoo` package; however, I now need to condition this function based on the `id` variable in my data frame. Is `ddply` the right function for this? If so, can someone help me please figure out how to get the output to be included in a new variable called `result` in the same data frame?

This is what I have so far:

```
# Load required libraries
library(zoo)
library(plyr)

# Create the data
data <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
              2, 2, 2), day = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
              8), value = c("NA", "1", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
              "NA", "NA", "1", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA")), .Names = c("id", 
              "day", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")

# Propagate the value of the first non-missing observation in data$value forward for each id
data$result <- na.locf(data$value, na.rm = FALSE)
```

Any thoughts on how to run the the `na.locf` function by each `id` would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1)** Firstly note that the `value` column is a character column with `"NA"` values, not `NA` values  so lets fix that first in ##.  Then create a wrapper function `na.locf.na` which uses `na.locf` in the [zoo package](http://cran.-rproject.org/package=zoo) and is the same except it defaults to `na.rm = FALSE`.  Finally use `ave` to apply `na.locf` by `id`:

```
library(zoo)

data2 <- transform(data, value = as.numeric(value)) ##

na.locf.na <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE, ...) na.locf(x, na.rm = na.rm, ...)
transform(data2, value = ave(value, id, FUN = na.locf.na))
```

**2)** or this compact alternative using [fn](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gsubfn/docs/fn) from the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) to represent `na.locf.na` inline in a more compact manner:

```
library(zoo)
library(gsubfn)

transform(data2, value = fn$ave(value, id, FUN = ~ na.locf(x, na.rm = FALSE)))
```

In either of these two cases the result is:

```
   id day value
1   1   0    NA
2   1   1     1
3   1   2     1
4   1   3     1
5   1   4     1
6   1   5     1
7   1   6     1
8   2   0    NA
9   2   1    NA
10  2   2    NA
11  2   3     1
12  2   4     1
13  2   5     1
14  2   6     1
15  2   7     1
16  2   8     1
```

**3)** We could alternately use dplyr together with zoo using `na.locf.na` from above:

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

data2 <- data %>% mutate(value = as.numeric(value)) # fix value column
data2 %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(value = na.locf.na(value))
```

If the [dplyr from CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/package=dplyr) does not work here try the one from github:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("hadley/dplyr")
```

**REVISIONS** Reorganized presentation and added alternatives.

Comment: Absolutely perfect -- thank you!  I have never used the `transform` function before, but I will definitely look into it further.  Thanks again.