# I don't succeed to use LOCF method as I want

Tags: r

I am now working on a dataset that has many missing values. I am using LOCF method to replace missing values (cause it is repeated measures). I used `na.locf`function to do the replacement of the missing values. Here is a simulation example I did on a dataframe I created

```
library(zoo)
ID<-c(rep(01,3),rep(02,3),rep(03,3),rep(07,3),rep(08,3),rep(10,3),rep(11,3),rep(13,3))
AA<-c(2,2,3,NA,2,3,4,1,NA,3,2,1,0,2,1,3,0,3,2,1,4,NA,2,NA)
BB<-c(2,3,0,4,1,3,1,0,2,3,4,3,1,0,NA,3,4,0,1,2,3,3,2,NA)
CC<-c(NA,2,3,4,3,4,2,3,2,3,5,1,NA,3,0,0,1,2,3,NA,3,2,1,2)
DD<-c(NA,3,3,2,1,13,4,22,2,3,NA,2,3,0,2,1,2,3,NA,3,2,1,4,2)
Jr<-rep(c("J0","J1","J2"),8)
data_rep<-data.frame(ID,Jr,AA,BB,CC,DD)
data_rep_locf<-na.locf(data_rep,na.rm=FALSE)
```

Here is the dataframe before the replacement of missing values.

```
data_rep
  ID Jr AA BB CC DD
1   1 J0  2  2 NA NA
2   1 J1  2  3  2  3
3   1 J2  3  0  3  3
4   2 J0 NA  4  4  2
5   2 J1  2  1  3  1
6   2 J2  3  3  4 13
7   3 J0  4  1  2  4
8   3 J1  1  0  3 22
9   3 J2 NA  2  2  2
10  7 J0  3  3  3  3
11  7 J1  2  4  5 NA
12  7 J2  1  3  1  2
13  8 J0  0  1 NA  3
14  8 J1  2  0  3  0
15  8 J2  1 NA  0  2
16 10 J0  3  3  0  1
17 10 J1  0  4  1  2
18 10 J2  3  0  2  3
19 11 J0  2  1  3 NA
20 11 J1  1  2 NA  3
21 11 J2  4  3  3  2
22 13 J0 NA  3  2  1
23 13 J1  2  2  1  4
24 13 J2 NA NA  2  2
```

Now here is the output after the replacement of missing values

```
data_rep_locf
   ID Jr AA BB CC DD
1   1 J0  2  2 NA NA
2   1 J1  2  3  2  3
3   1 J2  3  0  3  3
4   2 J0  3  4  4  2
5   2 J1  2  1  3  1
6   2 J2  3  3  4 13
7   3 J0  4  1  2  4
8   3 J1  1  0  3 22
9   3 J2  1  2  2  2
10  7 J0  3  3  3  3
11  7 J1  2  4  5  3
12  7 J2  1  3  1  2
13  8 J0  0  1  1  3
14  8 J1  2  0  3  0
15  8 J2  1  0  0  2
16 10 J0  3  3  0  1
17 10 J1  0  4  1  2
18 10 J2  3  0  2  3
19 11 J0  2  1  3  3
20 11 J1  1  2  3  3
21 11 J2  4  3  3  2
22 13 J0  4  3  2  1
23 13 J1  2  2  1  4
24 13 J2  2  2  2  2
```

If one look at the value of column AA and row 4 it took the value of row 3 of same column(that is 3). The ID 2 at day 0 took the value of day 2 of ID 1 while they are different individuals. I instead wanted NA for day 0 of ID2 in the column AA (In order to think to another way of replacement for values of day 0 without the LOCF method). How can I deal with this problem and using at the same time the LOCF method.

Best regards!!

Comment: Sounds like you want LOCF for each ID, maybe take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818493/carry-last-observation-forward-by-id-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) by** Use `by` to split the data into a component for each ID and use it to apply `na.locf` to each such component.  Finally `rbind` the components back together.  No additional packages are used.

```
do.call("rbind", by(data_rep, data_rep$ID, na.locf, na.rm = FALSE))
```

**2) ave** Another approach is to use `ave` on each column.  No additional packages are used.  Note that `na.locf0` is lke `na.locf` but only works on vectors and defaults to `na.rm = FALSE`.

```
AVE <- function(x) ave(x, data_rep$ID, FUN = na.locf0)
replace(data_rep, TRUE, lapply(data_rep, AVE))
```

**2a)** If it is ok to overwrite the input this can be written compactly as:

```
AVE <- function(x) ave(x, data_rep$ID, FUN = na.locf0)
data_rep[] <- lapply(data_rep, AVE)
```

**3) dplyr** Yet another approach is to use `group_by` in the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)

data_rep %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  na.locf(na.rm = FALSE) %>%
  ungroup
```

**4) data.table**

```
library(data.table)

DT <- as.data.table(data_rep)
DT[, na.locf(.SD, na.rm = FALSE), by = ID]
```

Note that this question is similar to this one except this question has multiple columns -- [Carry Last Observation Forward by ID in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818493/carry-last-observation-forward-by-id-in-r/23818888#23818888)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks G. Grothendieck for your response that solve my problem. But the dplyr method (Which i like usualy) seem to not work cause the value of row 4 in the column AA is still 3 (that is the last value of the prior subject) instead of NA